# non-tremolo repetition rate?

Tags: notation, tremolo

with reference to this answer, [tremolo notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/unknown-notation-thick-horizontal-bars-between-notes),

It's not completely clear to me how one should interpret two bars placed on a half-note, in 4/4 (or 2/4) time.  I'd always treated a two-bar marking as splitting the base-beat note into four pieces, so two bars on a half-note would mean playing sixteenths.  However,  some references such as [dolmetsch](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) indicate a double-slash half note to be played as eighth notes.

My particular concern in this case is the cello part to Dvorak's New World Symphony.   What's the proper interpretation?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the dolmetsch reference, the example shows a single-slash half note to be played as eighth notes.

Comment: @MunchyWilly  Ahhh, right .. my ancient eyes thought there were two,not one, slash thru the half note.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While having each slash represent a division of the note into equal halves would be logical, this doesn't hold true when on a half note (or longer note). Rather, a better general rule is that **each slash represents the number of beams equal to how many each note would have if written out.**

Thus, 2 slashes on a half note mean that the note should be divided into sixteenth-notes (which have 2 beams).