# Unknown Notation - Dotted Half notes connected by three Bars

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

My question is similar to the one posed here, [Unknown notation - thick horizontal bars between notes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/unknown-notation-thick-horizontal-bars-between-notes), but this notation is not exactly the same.  In the beginning bars of An der schönen blauen Donau - aka On the Beautiful Blue Danube - there is the notation in question.

Would someone please confirm that this notation represents a tremolo of evenly spaced 32nd notes for the duration of 6 beats in each bar

[image]

I apologize if this question has been asked before, I am unsure about piano terminology, and may have incorrectly phrased my search queries.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: In principle you are, but typically 6/8 time signature is counted with just two beats.

Comment: Hi jyapx, this is the exact same question as listed. It's a tremelo.